# Where to ask a question about a crashing linux software?

Tags: discussion

I would like to ask a question about a crashing Linux software (`kdenlive` to be more precise). Is this the right place for that? If not, which forum is best?

Where to ask a different question about video editing software?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can ask your question on this site, so long as it's an application that's running on some form of Unix or Linux.

In general when you come into a Stack Exchange site, you should always refer to the "Help Center" under the help pull-down in the upper right hand corner. All SE sites have a "On Topic" section which explains what is and what is not on topic.

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

I would think a more appropriate place for such is the Bug/Issue tracker, either of the distro or of the software itself (upstream).

Comment: Except that is a black hole that leads nowhere and I find when questions don't get closed they get resolved on SE sites.